# What is the relation between Attraction(राग) and Repulsion(द्वेष)?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, darshan

According to Verse 34 of chapter 3 in  **Srimadbhagwadgita**

> Attraction and repulsion are rooted in all sense-objects.  man should never allow himself to be swayed by them,   because they are the two principal enemies standing in the way of his redemption.

Can anyone describe the major relation between Attraction(राग) and repulsion(द्वेष)?

Comment: Not a question about the Hindu religion

Comment: I have edited my question to clear your confusion.Does you think that the Yoga Darshan or Gita is not related to hinduism ?

Comment: 1) You quote a verse about attraction and repulsion and then ask a question about passion and malice? If A is related to B what is the relation between C and D? Not a logical question. 2) "Everyone knows the reason for repulsion is attraction..." - No, everyone does not know. Why do you assume this? Still not a question about the Hindu religion.

Comment: No,You are right.It's not related to Hindu Dharma instead it is related to Sanatan Dharma Because Shankarji have told Maa Parvati that HINAM CHA DUSHWATWE HINDURITUCHATYE PRIYE.

Comment: *Raga* and *dvesa* are key concepts in spiritual practice and has been discussed in many scriptures. So the question is not off-topic.

Comment: The relation between attraction and repulsion is that they are opposite ends of the emotional nature of the Mind. The common source from which they come is called as attachment. When you are attached to something you have to either have a 'passion' for it, or you wil 'hate' it. Sri Krishna says that you must not be swayed by these. Thus He is asking us to destroy the source, develop Vairagya or Detachment. All the best!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Raga* means attachment, liking or desire for something and *dvesa* means aversion, dislike or hatred for something. So the relation between the two is that **they are opposite to each other**. But because the world is filled with dualities like hot-cold, pleasure-pain, etc., *liking for something can automatically create dislike for the opposite of that thing*. For example, if one likes hot coffee and tasty food then he will dislike cold coffee and tasteless food. If one has a liking for winter season, then he may dislike the others. Similarly, if one dislikes the winter season, then he will like any other.

So whether it is *raga* or *dvesa*, one can lead to another because the world is filled with objects of both kinds called as *dvanda* in the scriptures.. So Shri Krishna instructs to get rid of both of them. Whatever may it be, *raga* or *dvesa*, when one has it for certain person or certain being, he is bound to think about it all the time. If a person likes someone then he will think about him, and if a person hates someone, then also the person will think about him. So either of them is bad. Both has to be get rid of to fix the mind on God. Generally spiritual practitioners develop attachment towards God but in the way they tend to dislike *samsara* or the material world. But that is wrong, there should not be liking or disliking for anything in the world.

In that verse (BG 3.34) Shri Krishna tells that, this *raga* and *dvesa* exist in the senses because through the senses that the objects of the world is felt. And due to the nature of the world, while certain things are pleasurebale to the senses certain things are not. Due to the three fold material nature every one has liking and disliking for certain things as per their own nature. Every body is born into this delusion of dualities of the world:

> *iccha-dvesha-samutthena dvandva-mohena bharata
>
>   sarva-bhutani sammoham sarge yanti parantapa* [BG - 7.27]
>
> **Meaning**
>   O scion of Bharata, O conqueror of the foe, all living entities are born into delusion, bewildered by dualities arisen from desire and hate.

But because either of it causes attachment to material things and not God, Shri Krishna instructs to get rid of both.